# Xamarin.iOS can I have one class that some buttons can inherit from so they get the same looks?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm very new to Xamarin and I am currently working on a Xamarin.iOS project where I have added buttons in Xcode. How would I go about it if I want to style some of the buttons the same way without having to repeat myself in the code? Can I create a class or something that the specific buttons can inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about it if I want to style some of the buttons the
> same way without having to repeat myself in the code? Can I create a
> class or something that the specific buttons can inherit from?

**Answer**:This could be achieved through `Custom Renderer`.

**First**,in your shared project,create a base class:

```
CustomButton.cs


    public class CustomButton : Button
   {
   }
```

**Then**,in your iOS project,create a Custom Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace App26.iOS
{


   public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Cleanup
        }

        if (Control != null)
        {
            //set custom style here
            Control.TitleShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(1, 1);
            Control.SetTitleShadowColor(Color.Black.ToUIColor(), UIKit.UIControlState.Normal);
            Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            Control.Title(UIControlState.Selected);

         }
       }
    }
}
```

**Last but not least**, consume your custom button like below:

`<local:CustomButton/>`

MS official docs link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thank you! I am not working in Forms but I am assuming the logic is the same up until <local: customButton>. Do you know how I would do it in Xamarin.iOS project?

Comment: May I know how do you add button via `LanuchScreen.storyboard`, `view controller(.xlb)` or  `pure code(OC, Swift)`?

Comment: Some buttons I have added through the storyboard and some I add in code in the view controller

Comment: You can directly copy the buttons to the `LanuchScreen.storyboard` in Xamarin.iOS project and then use it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you elaborate please

Comment: Sure,please refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69675578/how-to-create-class-for-viewcontroller-in-xamarin-ios   for more details.